# Is there a document class for legal statements?

Tags: lyx, legal-style

I need to write a legal statement -- putting forth an argument for an American court.

Would there be a good class for that -- with references to the docket-number, etcætera --  or do I simply use KOMA2 Letter?

Comment: Kindly have a look here https://www.ctan.org/topic/legal

Comment: Haven‘t found packages or definitions on docket or pacer. However, you probably just need to write a simple \newcommand for it. However, in 2014 someone created LawTex, which somewhere provides a \docket command. Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Lawtex

Comment: Docket again. The most important statement here https://guides.library.lls.edu/c.php?g=497713&p=3407496#s-lg-box-10522118 is probably: each court uses its own system …

Comment: For an American court... I would not use TeX. I would use a word processor. It may be the case (not sure) that you should confine yourself to whatever can be written with WordPerfect, regardless of software used. It may also be the case that a specific font (or clone) is best. Perhaps something in the Schoolbook or Charter category. Ask around. In fact, the Clerk of the Court might be helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't be using raw TeX -- or even LaTeX. So looking for something supported by LyX...